# Stop jQuery from returning entire page into my div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So I've got a form that has the action of **'create_topic_parse.php'**, it sends the input values to that from **'create_topic.php'**, then they are inserted into the database. I am able to send any errors from the **'create_topic_parse.php'** file to the 'message' div in my **'create_topic.php'** page using the following code:

```
$("#submit").click( function() {
 // I've tried e.preventDefault(); here ^ but it's giving the same result.

      $.post( $("#topic_form").attr("action"),
             $("#topic_form :input").serializeArray(),
             function(info) {

               $("#message").empty();
               $("#message").html(info).css('color','#be4343');

            });

    $("#topic_form").submit( function() {
       return false; // Not working

    });
});
```

When the form is CORRECTLY input, and no errors are to be passed from the PHP file, the PHP script is supposed to redirect the user to **'view_topic.php?cid=".$cid."&tid=".$new_topic_id."&page=1'**. If I don't include the jQuery above, this works fine.

*Problem:* If I include the jQuery script, it returns the entire **'view_topic.php/etcetc'** page into '', which is bad.

So the question is, does anyone know how to prevent the entire page from being posted into this div, and actually redirect the user to 'view_topic.php' page when the form is correctly submitted?

Note: I've tried window.location, however I've then the issue of the concatonated variables from my PHP file that are input into the 'view_topic.php/etcetc' url. I am trying to get it to work with **header('location:...')**, like it does when the jQuery file isn't included.

Thanks in advance,

Richie

**Solution:**

jQuery + Ajax to PHP:

```
if($('#topic_title').val() == ''){
    $('#message').html("You need to give your topic a title.");
}
```

Using this code I was able to check whether each data entry existed, when all of the data values were existing I'd run the AJAX script within the same file passing each value into a variable like so:

```
var submit = $('#submit').val();
var topic_title = $('#topic_title').val();


$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "create_topic_parse.php",
        data: {submit:submit, topic_title:topic_title),
```

etc etc.

Comment: I think the `window.location='view_topic.php'` but what is the problem with that? Can you elaborate or show via code what that struggle is?

Comment: I'm concatenating variables into my header('location...) that are given by the PHP script when the form is submitted. Everything is then entered into the db.

Comment: On your php page, you should echo those variables into a json string using `echo json_encode($array_with_variables)` then when your current page receives the string back, it would parse the json array to an object, then you use the `window.location='view_topic.php?cid='+Parsed.cid+'&tid='+Parsed.tid+'&page=1'` and your current window will reload with the correct variables in your `$_GET`

Comment: How would I go about I return the json_encode to the .js file? - Sorry I've never used json before. Confession made. >_<

Comment: See the answer below. They just wrote out what I said (not exactly how I would do it, but more or less).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It'll work
when form is correctly submitted then only send some string like "correct", and in jquery let you check the ouput string. if it's "correct" then redirect it to view topic via javascript.

if you want to redirect the user to an specific page sent from server, then send from server something like this in json format.

write code on server something like this.

```
if ($condition==true) {
    $ajax_return = array(
        'message' => 'correct',
            'url' => 'your_redirect_url'
    );           
}
else
{
    $ajax_return = array(
        'message' => 'your user defined error message',
        'url' => 'leave it blank'
    );
}
$ajax_return = json_encode($ajax_return);
echo $ajax_return;
```

and now jquery on create_topic.php page

```
$("#topic_form").submit( function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.post( 
            $("#topic_form").attr("action"),
            $("#topic_form :input").serializeArray(),
            function(info) {
                   info= JSON.parse(info);                       
                   if(info.message="correct"){
                       window.location=info.url;
                   }
                   else{
                       $("#message").html('');
                       $("#message").html(info).css('color','#be4343');
                   }

            });

});
```

I'm sure now it'll work. If not, let me know.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid it's still returning 'view_topic.php?cid=".$cid."&tid=".$new_topic_id."&page=1' into the ('#message') div when submit is successful.

Comment: Just cooking dinner atm but I'll give it a try shortly. Thank you for responding so adamantly. I'll let you know how it goes.